# Area 51 converts the 1st character of target audience to lowercase - even for acronyms

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, area-51

I created a proposal in Area 51: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12972/abap-development.

The target audience is SAP developers.  However, the site keeps changing the first letter to lowercase, so it looks like the target audience is sAP developers.

Comment: just change it to "developers of SAP coding in ABAP"

Comment: @devinb: Yes, that's the obvious workaround.  Just wanted to get this out there.  I don't particularly care whether they fix it or not.

Comment: +1 I had the same issue with a proper noun a few weeks ago, and had to use @devin's workaround.

Comment: I have had to fix a few proper noun proposals using the workaround suggested above.

Comment: @Robert So is this a recognized "bug"(it's wrong), "Feature-request"(we'll fix it) or is it a "by-design"(we won't fix it)

Comment: @David Fullerton: what was fixed? In http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655 it is apparently not possible to change "christians and those ..." to "Christians and those ...". The following proposals also need proper nouns: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4262/cisco, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12913/java-platform-micro-edition, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11332/myanmar-asp-net, http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12913/java-platform-micro-edition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've made this a little better for acronyms: we don't lower case the first letter if the second letter is upper case.

Comment: what is the reason for lowercasing the first letter (except for the new rule)?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the sanctioned recommendation is to rearrange the sentence so that the first word of the description is not a [proper noun](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/propernoun.htm).