# Can first-letter lowercasing in proposal description on Area 51 be turned off?

Tags: support, area-51

**Update**: the [current behaviour has been reported as a bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56895/area-51-converts-the-1st-character-of-target-audience-to-lowercase-even-for-acr) (I think it is a feature); I am asking for a way to circumvent the current behaviour in certain cases.

Is there a way (for example, special markup or another workaround) to prevent lower casing of the first letter after "Proposed Q&A site for" in the description for a site proposal on Area 51?

Here are some examples where the lowercasing is not appropriate:

1. [Proposed Q&A site for pMs, themers, developers, site-builders, admins and businesses using or thinking about using the Drupal CMS](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2978/drupal-answers)
2. [Proposed Q&A site for iT Professionals or budding IT Professionals who want advice into how to develop and progress their career.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12887/it-careers)
3. [Proposed Q&A site for sAP Developers coding in ABAP](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/12972/abap-development)
4. [Proposed Q&A site for sAP Functional / Business Analysts SAP ABAP Developers SAP .NET Connector Developers XI / WebDynPro Developers SAP Enthusiasts SAP BASIS professionals](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13159/sap-knowledge-exchange)
5. [Proposed Q&A site for christians and those interested in Christianity.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11655/christianity)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug, see [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56895/area51-converts-1st-character-of-target-audience-to-lowercase-even-for-acronyms)

Comment: on that page it has now been classified as "by design".

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: With the exception of example 5 everything is "fixed" now, since now lowercase will only be applied if the second letter is not uppercase